# Taking multiple cells and using their info to create another cell

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I am trying to use the info from three different cells in a certain row to autofill another cell with the information I want. Its been awhile since I have used VBA and I don't quite know why I am getting "Object defined error". Here is my code and if you could help point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

```
Sub Conduit()

Sheets("Sheet4").Select

Dim celltxt As String
Dim celltxt2 As String
Dim celltxt3 As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 3

Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""

    celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("Bi").Text
    celltxt2 = ActiveSheet.Range("Fi").Text
    celltxt3 = ActiveSheet.Range("Di").Text

    If InStr(3, celltxt, "RMS") And InStr(3, celltxt2, "XHHW-2") And InStr(3, celltxt3, "1/C") Then
        [Ai].Value = "2"

    Else
        [Ai].Value = "999999"

    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? Have you tried stepping through the code with F8 to see where it errors out?

Comment: I'm guessing its the part where you try to assign values to `[Ai]`. What is that? Where have you defined it?

Answer (score 2):

This line
`celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("Bi").Text` is incorrect.

Try

`celltxt = ActiveSheet.cells(i,2).Text`

Same for Ai. You just can't intvar  in string  and expect it to be correct.

Comment: Yeah, this would be a problem too. You could also use `ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Text`

Comment: One more comment. the `.Text` property returns the visible text in a cell. If some of the text is hidden, `.Text` may not contain what you expect. The `.Value` property will contain all of the text in the cell.

Comment: @Trim agreed. Also `.Value2` is more adjacent to text property.